# "Query Cannot Be Updated because the FROM clause is not a simple single table name" Error

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-insert, openquery

I have a linked server in MS SQL Server to an ODBC data source referencing DBF files. These files are not in a database so I am using the OPENQUERY() syntax to access the tables. the SELECT query works just fine. Here is the Syntax for that:

```
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(VTESTCORP, 'SELECT * FROM [VNAME]')
```

But then when I try to append to one field in the table, I get this error

```
OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "VTESTCORP" returned message "Query cannot be updated because the FROM clause is not a single simple table name.".
Msg 7399, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "VTESTCORP" reported an error. The provider reported 
an unexpected catastrophic failure.
Msg 7343, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
The OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "VTESTCORP" could not INSERT INTO table "[MSDASQL]".
```

Here is the append OPENQUERY () query I am using:

```
INSERT OPENQUERY (VTESTCORP, 'SELECT NNAME from [VNAME]')
VALUES ('NEW NAME');
```

Right now I am just trying to test if appending to a linked DBF file works. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Why not use 4 part naming?

Comment: I would use the 4 part naming, but since these tables are not in a DB (they are standing alone in a folder) I do not know how to get the syntax.